# Rails 3: Link_to list item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some buttons which are basically overridden `<li>`s with CSS. I want to link the entire `<li>` link to a Rails action.

So I don't want to do this:

```
<li><%= link_to choice, { :action => "update", :id => @id, :response => index }, :remote => true %></li>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to <li>choice</li>, { :action => "update", :id => @id, :response => index }, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using routing helpers to generate the URL?

Comment: I am very new to Rails so the only reason I'm not using them is I don't know what that is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use html_safe

```
<%= link_to "<li>choice</li>".html_safe, { :action => "update", :id => @id, :response => index }, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Since answers uses Markdown formatting you need to select your HTML code and then press the `{}` button in order for it to come out right.

Answer (score 8):

use block

```
<%= link_to {...} do %>
  <li>choice</li>
<% end %>
```

note that rails 3.x uses `<%=` but rails 2.x uses `<%`

Comment: Quick note: the block format varies depending on the type of construct being used. For example, link_to will use `<%= .. %>`, but if still uses `<% .. %>`