# List Item Wrapping Link_to in Conjunction with Can

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I'm trying to do something very basic but am getting tripped up.

I am creating anchor tags using link_to, but I want these tags to be wrapped in li tags. 
I followed the steps on a previous post [Rails 3: Link_to list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238248/rails-3-link-to-list-item) but this wraps my LIs in As. I've tried this.

```
<%= link_to "<li>Site Specific Articles</li>".html_safe, site_specific_articles_path if can? :edit, SiteSpecificArticle %>
```

but it produces

```
<a href="/site_specific_articles"><li>Site Specific Articles</li></a>
```

when I want

```
<li><a href="/site_specific_articles">Site Specific Articles</a></li>
```

Any ideas are more than welcome on this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the `<li>` and `</li>` out of the `link_to`, meaning the conditional must wrap everything *(it needs to be taken out of the `link_to` as well)*

```
<% if can? :edit, SiteSpecificArticle %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Site Specific Articles", site_specific_articles_path %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

IMO, this is more readable anyway.

Comment: brilliant thanks. I knew it was simple :-). Any tips on keeping it tidy when there are multiple `can? :edit` conditions? e.g. sites, campaigns etc? or do I just have to bite the bullet on this one? Thanks again

Comment: If a single conditional like the one above has multiple conditions and is reused frequently, you might consider putting it into a helper method, however the sort of thing you're doing typically only happens a lot in one place: the navigation partial. If that's the case, I say just "bite the bullet". I have more detailed responses I could provide to this, but it's a bit out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Yeah not to worry. that is more than enough help. Thanks